# Exception while using Uiautomator to capture image/screenshot

Tags: android, junit, ui-automation

While using the UiautomatorTestcase class to capture the screenshot of my main activity I am facing the following exception.

The sample code which I'm using

```
public class MyActivityTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public UiautomatorAdaptxt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setUp();

    }

    public void testOpenMainActivity() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        -->Here I use the code to open my Activity<--
        getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(storePath);
    }
}
```

The exception I'm facing with is

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.takeScreenshot
        at 
.testOpenMainActivity(MyActivityTest
.java:31)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java
:124)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:8
5)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:76)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an Android 4.2 device or later to take screenshots this way.

This is because the `takeScreenshot` method was added in Android 4.2 or API Level 17 as the target is called.

See the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot%28java.io.File%29).

What's happening is that when you compile on your local machine you compile against android-17 or later containing this method, hence compilation succeeds. However, when deployed on a target android device at android-16, this method is missing. When the test code tries to call this method it throws the `NoSuchMethodError` exception.

As a workaround, you can take screenshots using adb like so

```
adb shell screencap -p /data/local/tmp/screen-capture.png
adb pull /data/local/tmp/screen-capture.png <localfile.png>
adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/screen-capture.png
```

Comment: Hi Vidstige thanks for the info, can you guide me regarding the path parameter used in the takeScreenshot (File storePath) Which path should I provide to view the captured image??.